# OpenBSD Home Server + Workstation on same machine?

Tags: home-networking, home-server, openbsd

I'd like to learn about secure networking (PKI, x509 certs, DNS, IPS, etc.) and generally harden my home network using OpenBSD. I only have one server with the horsepower (RAM, SSD, processors, etc.) and I'd like to use it as a workstation too.

**Is it possible to use a single home server to...**

1. Deploy a firewall, IPS, etc. AND
2. Have an OpenBSD workstation

**... on the same physical machine?**

**Something like this:**

[image] OR...

...should I keep the desktop env off the server?

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look into virtualization?

Comment: I'm familiar with virtualization, mainly using Hyper-V, VirtualBox, etc. to try out different OS's. How are you picturing it being used?